# Spritesheet filesize gets huge after compiling

Tags: xna, performance, memory

I have a 14x2 spritesheet which has 125 Kb in raw .png.
But as soon as I compile that to .xnb, it mutates to 4 MB.

So my question is: Why is that? And how can I fix that?

Comment: Different formats, different sizes. Have you tried different source file sizes? What are you compiling into the .xnb? Are you sure it's only that sprite sheet going in?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure. I have another spritesheet which has 10 MB in .xnb format. I think these filesize changes originate from spritesheets with a lot of frames. I would even go so far that the .xnb is every frame * original filesize

Answer (score 3):

I believe images in xnb format are uncompressed so image file size is purely a function of image size and colour depth.

Width * Height * Depth = Size

If your image is 1024px square at 32 bits per pixel, it'll be 4mb in size.

**Edit**

You could try using the DxtCompressed option, in the solution explorer > content project > image file > properties > texture format - change Color to DxtCompressed

Comment: So, reducing the bits from 32 to 16 will make the file 50% smaller

Comment: That is Correct

Answer (score 3):

The resources compiled in Debug mode generally comes bigger than the original. Try to compile in Release mode and see the size of the file in the Release folder.

Comment: I don't belive this is true. Do you have a source?

Comment: Just test yourself.

Comment: is true.. xnb are optimized in release mode and are smaller

Comment: I just checked it: Filesizes are all the same

Comment: IMX, how are the files you have tested? I have sprite sheets that in Debug mode gets size of 3mb and in Release mode, they change to 100kb.

Comment: @ClassicThunder Specifically, the XNB format has a compression mode that is basically equivalent to zipping the file. By default it is only turned on in release builds. The setting is in your *game* project properties (not the *content* project itself), under "Content Build".